# Planet Orbit "swept Area" Vs halo orbit "swept area"

Tags: orbital-mechanics, james-webb-telescope, halo-orbit

After plotting the JWST halo orbit to a flat plane, and finding that the halo **appears** to closely approximate an ellipse (yes, the halo has some 'potato chip' warping) I began to wonder. A planetary orbit sweeps out an equal area for a given time period. Would a halo orbit do the same?  Since there is no equivalent gravitational center for the halo,(EDIT: should have said 'gravitational center **AT** the halo') I'd guess 'NO'.  Since I have no means to crunch the numbers in a supportable manner I'd like the community here to look at this!

Question: In a Rotating Libration Point framework, would a "swept area per time unit" be the same?

[image]

came across this today.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the exact answer, but my guess is that it is approximately true for JWST for two reasons:

1. For *small perturbations* from L2, there are linear restoring forces that result in simple harmonic motion. This is true along the axis of rotation (z-axis) and also in the direction of rotation (y-axis).  In the ecliptic plane (x-y plane), the Coriolis force acts to automatically bend the resulting simple harmonic motion into an ellipse.
2. So, at least for small perturbations, there is an apparent linear central restoring force that gives rise to the elliptical orbits. Orbits arising from a central force conserve angular momentum which means the orbit sweeps out equal areas in equal times. This is true whether it's an inverse-square law (Kepler) or a linear law (Hooke). Orbits with Hooke's law correspond to simple harmonic motion.

Obviously the motions for JWST are not small and the family of halo orbits does incude some very extreme examples.  (These include highly elliptical orbits that pass close to the secondary body and are not centered very close to the Lagrange point.)

However, the JWST orbit seems relatively well-behaved. It is fairly well centered on L2 and it looks fairly elliptical.  Admittedly it's not a very small orbit and it's a bit warped, but I would still guess that "equal areas in equal times" works pretty well.

Here is a plot of the triangular areas for each 1-week interval and also the velocity.

[image: area swept per week]
[image]

It's interesting that the velocity is highest at the inner edge of the orbit (closest to Earth).  But the main feature is the twice-around variation with the velocity lowest at each y-axis extremum. The velocity variation is almost 2:1, whereas the area per unit time variation is only 4:5. So most of the velocity variation is cancelled by the radial variation - though not to the extent I was expecting.

To clarify: the first graph shows the area of the triangle $(0,0,0),r_1,r_2$ where $r_1$ is the 3D vector position at the beginning of a week and $r_2$ at the end of the week. The second graph shows the speed $|r_2-r_1|$. The vectors include x,y, and z.

[update per @BradV comment] Moving the center can get rid of the once-around component in the swept-area graph:

[image: reduced once-around graph]

[update per @BradV comment #2] Moving the center to the centroid of the area enclosed by the orbit doesn't eliminate the once-around component quite as well. It doesn't take into account the velocity round the orbit (faster on the near-earth side).

[image]

Comment: "Orbits arising from a central force conserve angular momentum" might need some qualifications; exclude velocity dependent forces and perhaps those with other than $r^{-2}$ dependence? I wonder if "conservative potential" is helpful vocabulary?

Comment: @uhoh it's true for any central force as long as the angular momentum is measured around that central point. (but, as you say, only r and 1/r^2 give closed orbits)

Comment: @Roger Wood: I wonder what your 'area' graph represents. Is it a calculation of the warped potato chip surface or a planar surface. What was used as center? RLP 0,0,0 or point on 'chip'? ALSO... is speed graph the full Vx,Vy,Vz  or just Vy?

Comment: I had done rough calculations of expected orbital velocities (Vy only) based on position relative to sun (ignored +/- Z movement) and came up with similar numbers...  in my mind demonstrating that coriolis is not the primary factor for halo tilt. Agree/disagree??

Comment: @BradV I've added a note to clarify.  PS. If I were to move the center slightly from L2, I could get rid of most of the once-around variation in swept area.

Comment: @BradV Yes, I think the z-motion and the x-y motion are somewhat independent. You can happily change the z-motion relative phase by 180 and flip from North to South orbit orbit.

Comment: @Roger Wood   I wonder if "swept area" variations would increase or decrease if a different origin were used.    I estimate the origin of the ellipse to be approx X -84,000,  Y 0,  Z -60,000

Comment: @BradV I tweaked your numbers a bit but see the new graph I added

Comment: @Roger Wood: Uh, OK? I'd like to know your reasoning for selectng the origin you used.
 I arrived at my numbers when I scaled your halo orbit plots and estimated values
 (for lack of a better term) "estimated averaged plane location".
 Just FYI, Grand Marnier has been involved in this communique.

Comment: @BradV nothing at all scientific, I'm afraid.  I started with your numbers then twiddled and twiddled until I got the least wiggly line.  I agree it doesn't look very centered but I think the larger than expected x displacement corresponds to the speed being faster on the inner edge of the orbit.  i.e. it's slighly Keplerian along the x-axis

Comment: @Roger Wood  Very interesting! I was thinking of suggesting just such an exercise. However, while you have arrived at the 'flattest' area graph line I believe you've clouded the central issue. I don't believe using a center which yields the least area variation is relevant to the comparison of time related Planet orbit swept area vs halo orbit swept area. Its like cooking the books to get answers to match

Comment: Perhaps a more "representative" halo orbit center could be determined by seeking the lowest total area summation using points from timeframe .75 thru 1.75 yr (discarding entry stabilization period and end period variation). I would be interested in knowing how closely a computed center based on lowest total area corresponds with my visual estimate. My reasoning here is that the halo location has been purposefully positioned well inward from the L2 point to make sure JWST doesn't have opportunity to get away from us.

Comment: @BradV I have this all in excell, so it's easy using the 'solver'. It doesn't give what I expect at all.  Neither the point that minimises the area, nor the point that minimizes the variance are sensible.  In retrospect, the area is pretty much constant for any point inside the orbit but reaches a shallow minimum very close to the inside edge of the orbit.  The varance goes to zero seen from any point at infinity.  We probably want the center of mass of either the orbital area or the orbital line.  I need to think about that.

Comment: @BradV If I minimize sum(r1*r2*Area), I get (-114192.1735, 0, -51868.02544). If I minimise sum(r1*r2*delta_r), I get (-119939.6777, 0, -46816.92989).  I think these correspond, respectively, to the center of mass of the orbit area sheet and the center of mass of the wire-frame orbit. These are a more similar to what you were suggesting.

Comment: @Roger Wood: so... what does the swept area graph look like using 114192,0,51868 ?? What are your thoughts regarding using this estimated centroid vs your earlier graphs?  (by the way, the term centroid is used to discuss points like these. I used to work these solutions all the time when calculating structural stiffnesses and integrity.

Comment: @BradV - done!  Not sure the best quantity to minimize to get the least variation in swept area per week.  If I minimize the variance, it just finds some very distant reference point.  Maybe try variance / area^2?

Comment: trying to achieve least variation is fool's errand and not consistent with conservation of momentum.

Comment: @BradV if we could identify a single point around which there was zero variation in swept area, then that would correspond with there being effectively a central force.  But it only seems to be somewhat true for these large halo orbits.  For small perturbations from L2 that result in simple harmonic motion, it should be exactly true - even though these may be Lissajous figures and not closed orbits.

Comment: @Roger Wood:  thank you so much for being so helpful to me. I am new to this and trying to integrate so many different concepts into a useful whole. Here I find myself on the embarrassing end of a comment I've used on other engineers... "I've given you an answer that is 100% correct but is of no use to you because you've asked the wrong question."  One question in particular I got wrong was about your 'speed' graph. After trying to make some things work out it dawned on me that the graph is nothing more than distance/time and has no 'direction'  other than making assumption

Comment: that max speed happens at max Z, prograde (and in that moment) parallel to earth orbit and the lower speed peak is at min Z ... also prograde and parallel to earth orbit. Do I have it now?       I meant dist/time  V years

Comment: @BradV yup, that sounds right.  The orbit takes about 6 months. There are two minima in speed per orbit 3 months apart.  These occur at the 'forward' and 'backward' extremes of the ellipse. Similarly, there are two speed maxima per orbit. These occur when it's closest to Earth and farthest from Earth.  The higher/faster peak occurs when it's closest to Earth traveling the same direction as Earth. .

Comment: @Roger Wood strange to find comfort in orbital mechanics considering world events of 02/24/2022.

Comment: @Roger Wood I'm bouncing between Pachelbel's Canon in D major and the Who's Baba O'riley

Comment: @BradV I don't know anything about music but the events in Europe are very disturbing

Comment: @Roger Wood considering Sagan's 'Blue Dot' ... I'm inclined to wonder about guitarist Joe Walsh (before Eagles) when he released his album 'So What'. Maybe everything means nothing.